# How send N get requests where N > 10 URLS

Tags: http, go, request

I'm trying to make N get requests, but my code work for 8 URLs but 10 always stack without issue.

I'm new to GO so I can't understand the issue.

I'm trying to write an app to beat .NET app with the same task.

Could you please suggest what is wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    //"bufio"
    "time"
)

type HttpResponse struct {
    url      string
    response *http.Response
    err      error
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, world3.")

    var urls []string = []string{
    "www.webmagnat.ro",
    "nickelfreesolutions.com",
    "scheepvaarttelefoongids.nl",
    "tursan.net",
    "plannersanonymous.com",
    "saltstack.com",
    "deconsquad.com",
    "migom.com",
    "tjprc.org",
    "worklife.dk",
    "food-hub.org"}

    start := time.Now()
    results := asyncHttpGets(urls)

    f, err := os.Create("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }


    for _, result := range results {
        fmt.Printf("%s status: %s\n", result.url,
            result.response.Status)

            l, err := f.WriteString(result.url+"\n")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                f.Close()
                return
            }
            _ = l
    }
    t := time.Now()
    elapsed := t.Sub(start)
    fmt.Printf("Ellipsed: %s\n", elapsed)

    err = f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }


    fmt.Println("Buy, world2.")
}


func asyncHttpGets(urls []string) []*HttpResponse {
    ch := make(chan *HttpResponse, len(urls)) // buffered
    responses := []*HttpResponse{}
    for _, url := range urls {
         go func(url string) {
            fmt.Printf("Fetching %s \n", url)
            resp, err := http.Get("http://" + url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Failed to fetch %s\n", err)
                return
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
                fmt.Printf("HTTP Response Status : %v", resp.StatusCode)
                bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                bodyString := string(bodyBytes)

                fmt.Printf("HTTP Response Content Length : %v\n", len(bodyString))
            }

            ch <- &HttpResponse{url, resp, err}
        }(url)
    }

    for {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            fmt.Printf("%s was fetched\n", r.url)
            responses = append(responses, r)
            if len(responses) == len(urls) {
                return responses
            }
        case <-time.After(50 * time.Millisecond):
            fmt.Printf(".")
        }
    }

    return responses

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/pcKYYM_PgIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue here is that you aren't returning a response in the case of an error, so the `len(responses) == len(urls)` is likely to never match, forcing your loop to continue forever.

Start by adding a `sync.WaitGroup` for the concurrent requests

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    ch := make(chan *HttpResponse) 
    responses := []*HttpResponse{}
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            defer wg.Done()
```

Then you can range over the responses until all outstanding goroutines are done

```
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for r := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("%s was fetched\n", r.url)
        responses = append(responses, r)
    }

    return responses
```

You then have to decide how to handle the responses, are you going to read them in the concurrent call, or return their bodies unread. Since you will want to *always* attempt to consume the bodies if you want to re-use the connection, and since you've deferred the `Body.Close()`, this currently needs to happen within the same function call. You can either change the `httpResponse` type to make this possible, or replace the `resp.Body` with a buffer containing the response.

Finally you will want to have some sort of timeouts for the client (probably using a `Context`), and place a limit on the number concurrent requests being made.

Comment: It works. Thanks. But still not working with N > 1000.

Comment: @Mediator, which is why I said you need to limit concurrency and ensure requests can timeout

Comment: Yes, I found some solution https://github.com/remeh/sizedwaitgroup but still doesn't work for 1000 request and 8 pool limit size can't work too. now I have some strange issue '2020/02/11 10:44:19 unexpected EOF'

Comment: @Mediator: that's not really related to the concurrency problems you've shown here. A connection unexpectedly closed for some reason, but that's not something we can diagnose from this example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning in case of error without writing to the channel. See your `if err != nil { return }` statement. Because you don't write to the channel the `len(responses) == len(urls)` statement can never be true.

```golang
 go func(url string) {
            fmt.Printf("Fetching %s \n", url)
            resp, err := http.Get("http://" + url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Failed to fetch %s\n", err)
                return
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
                fmt.Printf("HTTP Response Status : %v", resp.StatusCode)
                bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                bodyString := string(bodyBytes)

                fmt.Printf("HTTP Response Content Length : %v\n", len(bodyString))
            }

            ch <- &HttpResponse{url, resp, err}
        }(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to add the Wait Group construct, because when two threads execute, the main thread ends. see: https://yourbasic.org/golang/wait-for-goroutines-waitgroup/

```
func asyncHttpGets(urls []string) []*HttpResponse {
    ch := make(chan *HttpResponse, len(urls)) 
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    responses := []*HttpResponse{}
    for _, url := range urls {
        go func(url string) {
            wg.Add(1)
            fmt.Printf("Fetching %s \n", url)
            resp, err := http.Get("http://" + url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Failed to fetch %s\n", err)
                return
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
                fmt.Printf("HTTP Response Status : %v", resp.StatusCode)
                bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                bodyString := string(bodyBytes)

                fmt.Printf("HTTP Response Content Length : %v\n", len(bodyString))
            }

            ch <- &HttpResponse{url, resp, err}
        }(url)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    for {
        select {
        case r := <-ch:
            fmt.Printf("%s was fetched\n", r.url)
            responses = append(responses, r)
            if len(responses) == len(urls) {
                return responses
            }
        case <-time.After(50 * time.Millisecond):
            fmt.Printf(".")
        }
    }
    return responses
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it stuck in some place. Can't see where are you use wg.Done

Comment: @Mediator there is no way to do the work for you. I pointed out problems with the reason and provided a link to an example of WG

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following library:

**Requests**: *A Go library for reduce the headache when making HTTP requests (20k/s req)*

https://github.com/alessiosavi/Requests

It's developed for solve the `to many open files` dealing with parallel requests.

The idea is to allocate a list of request, than send them with a configurable "parallel" factor that allow to run only "N" request at time.

Initialize the requests (you have already a set of urls)

```golang
// This array will contains the list of request
var reqs []requests.Request

// N is the number of request to run in parallel, in order to avoid "TO MANY OPEN FILES. N have to be lower than ulimit threshold"
var N int = 12

// Create the list of request
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    // In this case, we init 1000 request with same URL,METHOD,BODY,HEADERS 
    req, err := requests.InitRequest("https://127.0.0.1:5000", "GET", nil, nil, true) 
    if err != nil {
        // Request is not compliant, and will not be add to the list
        log.Println("Skipping request [", i, "]. Error: ", err)
    } else {
        // If no error occurs, we can append the request created to the list of request that we need to send
        reqs = append(reqs, *req)
    }
}
```

At this point, we have a list that contains the requests that have to be sent.
Let's send them in parallel!

```golang
// This array will contains the response from the givens request
var response []datastructure.Response

// send the request using N request to send in parallel
response = requests.ParallelRequest(reqs, N)

// Print the response
for i := range response {
    // Dump is a method that print every information related to the response
    log.Println("Request [", i, "] -> ", response[i].Dump())
    // Or use the data present in the response
    log.Println("Headers: ", response[i].Headers)
    log.Println("Status code: ", response[i].StatusCode)
    log.Println("Time elapsed: ", response[i].Time)
    log.Println("Error: ", response[i].Error)
    log.Println("Body: ", string(response[i].Body))
}
```

You can find example usage into the [example folder](https://github.com/alessiosavi/Requests/blob/master/example/req_example.go) of the repository.

***SPOILER***:

> *I'm the author of this little library*